# Sorting an Array with a Scanner Prompt (Java)

Tags: java

I am having trouble executing a sort command to my program which allows the user to fill an array based on data they enter input. Once the data is entered, I want the program to sort the results in ascending order.

```
//Start of code

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class RaceCarArray {
public static void main(String args[]) {

// variables used that aren't initialized 
int numberCars;
int i, j;
int carsInField;
// intro popup
int start = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
            "This program will output the times of race cars entered", "Race 
Car Times", 
JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);
// User entry defines array length
numberCars = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter how 
many cars are in the 
field"));

// Declare Array and sets memory to user entry
double carTimes[];
carTimes = new double[numberCars];
carsInField = carTimes.length;

// for loop limited by length of array
for (i = 0; i < carTimes.length; i++){
// User enters times for each car. 
String value = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, String.format("Please enter 
time for car " + ( i +1 
) + " (mm.ss)"));
double singleCarTime = Double.parseDouble(value);
//each entry is placed in an ascending column on the array
carTimes[i] = singleCarTime;
}

//uses the length of the array to output how many cars there were
System.out.println("\nThere are " + carsInField + " cars that raced today");

// for loop prints out each car time matched with car number
for (j = 0; j < carTimes.length; j++){
System.out.printf("\nCar number " + (j +1) + "'s time was %.2f" , 
carTimes[j]);
}
//Program completion message
System.out.println("\n");
System.out.println("Thank you for using my program!");
}//end main

} //end class

//End of code
```

Any help?

Comment: Take a look at `Arrays.sort()`.

Comment: Yes. I absolutely tried that in many locations in the code, but it is giving me an error saying it cannot find the symbol.

Comment: Did you `import java.util.Arrays;` ?

Comment: Now when I enter the amount of elements in the array I want from the scanner prompt it is saying "Exception in thread 'main'... Out of Bounds Exception"...

Comment: Just a tip, comments are great but you don't have to comment everything. This reduces readability instead of improving it.

Comment: @RScrilla That seems to be unrelated to code you presented, update your code or ask another question

Comment: @Ecto Yes, that code has come up only after I added your suggestion. Anyway someone else has found the fix, thanks for those who tried.